# How to create openssh keys on iOS via Objective-C code

Tags: objective-c, openssh

We can get openssh keys by order 'ssh-keygen...', or get openssl keys by order 'openssl genrsa...'. But can I do this in my iOS app via Objective-C code? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you calling Objective-C OC?...

Comment: @EmilioPelaez Yes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use a library like OpenSSL to generate the keys. This isn't Objective-C, but you can interact with C libraries since Objective-C is a superset. You will need to read the documentation to fully understand how the library works, but this is a quick example:

```
RSA *myrsa;
unsigned long e = RSA_3;
BIO* out = NULL;
myrsa = RSA_generate_key(2048,e,NULL,NULL);

out=BIO_new(BIO_s_file());

if (myrsa == NULL) {
    /* error handling here /*
}
```

You will want to write the key data out somewhere. Without a more specific example of what you are doing, this is the best I can offer.

For information on using OpenSSL libraries within your project, see: https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/OpenSSL

Comment: Thanks for your help!! Let me have a try.

Comment: Good luck! Follow up if you have any more questions.

Comment: I am in the same boat, trying to generate private and public SSH-key on an iOS-device. I have OpenSSL running and can successfully create keys with RSA_generate_key. But I don't find information on how to continue and create an SSH-public key from the generated private key. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @CinderBiscuits I have a public key pem file "public-key.pem" and i want to generate "cnf" fingerprint. In terminal i can do this with commands
$ ssh-keygen -i -f public-key.pem -m PKCS8 -i > pubkey-ssh.pub # Convert to a SSH-formatted public key
$ awk '{print $2}' pubkey-ssh.pub | base64 -d | sha256sum | awk '{print $1}' | xxd -r -p | base64
How can i achieve this using OpenSSL in Objective-C