# Create SSH RSA key pair with PEM encoding using OpenSSL

Tags: objective-c, c, ssh, openssl

I am trying to generate OpenSSH key pairs on iOS. I now stuck how to create/extract a public ssh-RSA key from a PEM, equivalent to this:

```
ssh-keygen -y -f ~/.ssh/private
```

This is how I am creating the private key, which seems to create a valid key pair.

```
const int kBits = 1024;
const int kExp = 3;

int keylen;
int pub_len;
char *pem_key;

RSA *rsa = RSA_generate_key(kBits, kExp, 0, 0);
BIO *bio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
PEM_write_bio_RSAPrivateKey(bio, rsa, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);

keylen = BIO_pending(bio);
pem_key = calloc(keylen+1, 1); /* Null-terminate */

BIO_read(bio, pem_key, keylen);

printf("%s", pem_key);

BIO_free_all(bio);
RSA_free(rsa);
free(pem_key);
```

I am new to cryptography and C, any hints or clues are much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which are you trying to do... (1) Extract a RSA key from an existing PEM encoded SSH key; or (2) Create a RSA key from scratch using OpenSSL that is in a format for OpenSSH? Your sample code looks like (2), but your question preamble asks for (1). Also checkout `do_convert_to_ssh2` and `sshkey_to_blob` in OpenSSH's source file [`ssh-keygen.c`](https://github.com/openssh/libopenssh/blob/master/ssh/ssh-keygen.c) and [`key.c`](https://github.com/openssh/libopenssh/blob/master/ssh/key.c).

Comment: jww thanks for your answer! Sorry for the confusion. My main goal is to create an OpenSSH key pair on iOS (2) (which seems not to be the easiest task). I may have gotten this wrong, but as I understand it a private OpenSSL key can be used as a private key in OpenSSH, and from this, I create an OpenSSH public key, or am I wrong about this?

Comment: I have found this answer but I am kind of stuck after generating the RSA key...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40863651/how-to-create-openssh-keys-on-ios-via-objective-c-code