# Convert pem public key to ssh-rsa public keys using "ssh-keygen" in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssh, openssh, pem

I want to pem public key and I want to generate ssh-rsa public keys using "ssh-keygen". I can achieve this using ssh-keygen in terminal (as show below)

```
ssh-keygen -i -f publicKey.pem -m PKCS8 -i > pubkey-ssh.pub
```

"ssh-rsa" public key form above command (expected):

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQC6qU2kfO17CC8iI8ZQdv+1ajM9AInm4RR6k1mBuGHXfvq87Y9ly/NihzQxWmkUvMKm8RVg4s+2Dj+vO1P06Q3/lTgDGMUHajPzljcVvqYkJU3hxDbH4h+FRgR/Lf/6q6b2M70qHSwSIAW3kK+iTedPximOOZeAOISa50wqE/Tr6hy5lxbAFMt54OSCgxiUSXql3C+e2zPRwihTcpk1eZZE1LVvw09gOOM4cNi4Xc3xkJZL/1LOA3aoZdjxkCIa1fdVFZ4aJRtZyoYAXPTGtVJcLiJlaxD4JKp/Dgoy9N88nuyYLtrNyuxq5i0Qs8Spx/jZQ+5Bu47ozeX5kAGPDUo9
```

I want to achieve the above unix command in iOS app using Objective-C (or c). 
I found some similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40863651/how-to-create-openssh-keys-on-ios-via-objective-c-code), but doesn't work for me.
I also found [openSSH c library](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable), but can't figure out due to lack of documentation.

Please help me any any one having any idea on this. Thanks in advance.

Update: My Implementation

```
NSData *data = nil;
const unsigned char *pp = (const unsigned char *)pkcs1Data.bytes;
RSA *rsa = d2i_RSAPublicKey(NULL, &pp, pkcs1Data.length);
if (rsa) {
    unsigned char *pOut = NULL;
    int length = i2d_RSA_PUBKEY(rsa, &pOut);
    if (pOut) {
        if (length > 0) {
            data = [NSData dataWithBytes:pOut length:length];
        }
        free(pOut);
    }
    RSA_free(rsa);
}
```

Comment: Describe "doesn't work for me"

Comment: @Brandon I was not getting the expected value